# How to sort table alphabetically by name initial?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table contains columns 'employeename' and 'id', how can I sort the 'employeename' column following alphabetical order of the names initial?

Say the table is like this now:

```
employeename    rid    eid
Dave             1      1
Ben              4      2
Chloe            6      6
```

I tried the command `ORDER BY`, it shows what I want but when I query the data again by `SELECT`, the showed table data is the same as original, indicting `ORDER BY` does not modify the data, is this correct?

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee
ORDER BY employeename ASC;
```

I expect the table data to be modified (sorted by names alphabetical order) like this:

```
employeename    rid    eid
Ben              4      2
Chloe            6      6
Dave             1      1
```

Comment: in an RDBMS, records in the table are stored in no particular order. Only an explicit `order by` guarantees that rows will be returned in a desired order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the showed table data is the same as original, indicting ORDER BY does not modify the data, is this correct?

Yes, this is correct. A `SELECT` statement does not change the data in a table. Only `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `INSERT` or `TRUNCATE` statements will change the data.

However, your question shows a misconception on how a relational database works.

Rows in a table (of a relational database) are not sorted in any way. You can picture them as balls in a basket.

If you want to display data in a specific sort order, the **only** (really: the *only*) way to do that is to use an `ORDER BY` in your SELECT statement. There is no alternative to that.

---

Postgres allows to define a VIEW that includes an `ORDER BY` which might be an acceptable workaround for you:

```
CREATE VIEW sorted_employee;
AS
SELECT * 
FROM employee
ORDER BY employeename ASC;
```

Then you can simply use

```
select *
from sorted_employees;
```

But be aware of the drawbacks. If you run `select * from sorted_employees order by id` then the data will be sorted twice. Postgres is not smart enough to remove the (useless) `order by` from the view's definition.

---

Some related questions:

- [Default row order in SELECT query - SQL Server 2008 vs SQL 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236352)
- [What is the default SQL result sort order with 'select *'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059131)
- [Is PostgreSQL order fully guaranteed if sorting on a non-unique attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263715)
- [Why do results from a SQL query not come back in the order I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999913)

Comment: *Rows in a table (of a relational database) are not sorted in any way. You can picture them as balls in a basket.*

Does this mean there is no need to sort the data in a database, the data can exist in any order, what matters is how the data is fetched and viewed?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu: correct (actually you can't really "sort the data in the database")