# Django DateField ordering logic in case of equal DateField values

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to understand what is the ordering logic of django of `DateField` in case the dates are equal? I've got a model that has a `DateField` and `DateTimeField` (irrelevant fields taken out).

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

The ordering for the model is as such:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_time', '-created_at']
```

Note that previously I didnt have the `created_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` at all and sorted only via `-created_at`. I added the additional `DateTimeField` just for testing purposes and it didnt affect the outcome of the `DateField` ordering in any way.

Here you can see the order how the objects were created in DB:
[image]

And this is the order how the objects are actually ordered on the `ListView` page:

[image]

The slug field in DB can be used as reference in order to understand which object in the template corresponds to which object in the DB.

As you can see the first `DateTimeField` order works as expected, however the ordering by `DateField` is not the same as the order in the DB.

What is more interesting that if I will go to my `UpdateView` and update the "Summernote" objects content (not messing with dates) then the ordering again changes although the dates and times in DB were not changed.

See the order difference after each update of the object (each column is a different snapshot from the same view after updating the object):
[image]

No changes to DB to illustrate that nor `DateField` nor `DateTimeField` were changed after updating the object:
[image]

I have a custom queryset in my ListView but it is not affecting the ordering as far as I can tell

```
def get_queryset(self):

    shifts = re.findall('standard|shifts|other', self.request.path)
    queryset = super(ListAd, self).get_queryset()
    queryset = queryset.filter(city=self.kwargs['city'], category=self.kwargs['category'],
                               shift__in=shifts,
                               expire__gte=date.today(),
                               publish_status=True)
    return queryset
```

Why the strange and seemingly inconsistent ordering in case of equal dates? What other aspects does django take in to consideration when ordering objects that have equal `DateField` values? DB engine is PostgreSQL 13.1

Comment: If you do `print(queryset.query)` you can see if there is some more ordering happening.

Comment: This behavior seems to be more on the database engine rather than django. You might want to add tags with your specific database so those who know more about your database might be able to answer

Comment: @RuudvandenBoomen queryset.query returns the ordering as is in the model - ORDER BY "ads_ad"."created_time" DESC, "ads_ad"."created_at" DESC

Comment: @BrianDestura thank you for leading to think about the DB engine rather then django in this case. I found the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263715/is-postgresql-order-fully-guaranteed-if-sorting-on-a-non-unique-attribute Postgres doesnt have any ordering by itself, meaning that the result is somewhat random in case of equal values. A solution would be to add a 3rd ordering argument such as object.id