# SELECT with condition on second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select records from 3 tables using a JOIN which is working well but I now need to add some additional conditions to the SELECT which I can't figure out. My current select works like this:

```
SELECT user.*, address.*, state.* FROM user 
LEFT JOIN address ON user.id = address.user_id 
LEFT JOIN state ON user.id = state.user_id
```

Now, the address and state could have multiple records but both tables have a bit field to indicate that they are the primary record and that's the one I want to select. I have tried adding a `WHERE address.state = b'1'` to the statement but it only returns those records that have a primary record, what I would ideally like to do is select the top record from the address/state table sorted by the primary field so the primary will be selected if it exists but the next record will be selected if there is no primary.

How can I achieve this with MySQL 5?

Answer (score 3):

Add the condition to your `LEFT JOIN`:

```
LEFT JOIN address ON ( user.id = address.user_id AND address.state = b'1' )
```

The left join will only return rows that match this criteria, but you will still get `users` without a primary address.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That is a step in the right direction. Is there a way to order the JOIN'd results rather than have a WHERE clause? So if a user has a primary address always pick that but if not just pick the next one primary or not?

Comment: @JWood Yes - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999913/why-do-results-from-a-sql-query-not-come-back-in-the-order-i-expect

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, and you are asking to pick the match ranked highest, in which case you need to write a subquery. You should ask that as a new question.

Comment: I think I do need a subquery in this case as ORDER only works on the primary table. I'll ask another questions. Thanks