# SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure output results in different order when executing multiple times

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Just encountered an odd behavior during our regression with a stored procedure which output thousands of records:

The stored procedure could output the results in different orders with same parameters if it's being called more than 20 times in a short while.

Anyone got any idea about this behavior?

For some reason, we are not able to specify the order explicitly in the stored procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do results from a SQL query not come back in the order I expect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999913/why-do-results-from-a-sql-query-not-come-back-in-the-order-i-expect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parallel query plan sounds a likely culprit ( or different query plans being used on different runs).

If you are not explicitly ordering with an `ORDER BY`, then no order is guaranteed.

Can you post the Stored Procedure and a query plan?

Comment: yes, it was due to parallel query plan. an interesting article - http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx

the stored procedure is very complex and takes a few seconds to execute normally and that explainis the parallel palns used, as spotted with our testing