# FULL OUTER JOIN - Result rows are showing in different order than expected

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-order-by, outer-join

I am following a tutorial for learning SQL and working on Google BigQuery Sandbox. For FULL OUTER JOIN my result is showing in different order than the result in the video. How can I fix this? (P.S. I am using the dataset given by them and I created the dataset and tables similar, and we both are using the exact same code.)

```
`SELECT employees.name AS employee_name,
   employees.role AS employee_role,
   departments.name AS department_name
FROM employee_data.employees
FULL OUTER JOIN employee_data.departments
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id`
```

Result I am getting (Julie Jones in row 1), [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F12Xp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF4o5.png)

But the result provided in the tutorial (expected result) (Dave Smith in row 1), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0fm5.png)

Comment: In general in database theory order does not matter and is not guaranteed ... you can control order (generally, but there are pitfalls) using `ORDER BY` clauses in your queries. If you get the same results, but in a different order, that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is technically a duplicate of [Why do results from a SQL query not come back in the order I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999913/why-do-results-from-a-sql-query-not-come-back-in-the-order-i-expect).

You should use the `ORDER BY` clause to enforce the order of your columns. Since you are using `FULL OUTER JOIN` you should probably expect a handful of `NULL` values.

You can handle those in your Order By and put them first by adding `ISNULL(MyNullColumnName), MyNullColumnName` to your order by clause.

I've thrown together a very small simple fiddle to demonstrate managing nulls and how they are displayed in your query you may find useful. MySql doesn't include a `NULLS FIRST/LAST` like some other RDBMS to my knowledge so it must all be done through the order by.

[Ordering with NULL in MySql](https://dbfiddle.uk/mWModVxo)